# How index can help speed up SELECT query

Tags: android, sqlite, optimization, indexing

```
query = "SELECT id AS _id, entry_id, r_ele_value, k_ele_value, gloss_value FROM search_eng WHERE r_ele_value LIKE '"+hiragana+"%' LIMIT 20";
```

This query is working very slow. So I have created index for r_ele_value in [SQLite Expert Professional](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Servers/Database-Utils/SQLite-Expert.shtml).

[image]

How to use created index to speed up data retrieval from large table(about 20MB)?

Answer (score 1):

In theory the [Query Planner](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html) should use your index automatically.

> Most of the time, the query planner in SQLite does a good job on its
>   own and without outside help. However, the query planner needs indices
>   to work with and it usually falls to the programmer to add indices to
>   the schema that are sufficient for the query planner to accomplish its
>   task.

---

Also, you might be insterested in the [Query Optimizer Overview](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html) article, there are some additional details described in how queries are performed.

Comment: Thank you @dst for links, I will read them and optimize my query

Answer (score 0):

For searches in big databases, you should actually take a look to the FTS3 tables with SQLite. This extension is meant to execute full text searches and is more efficient than a `LIKE`.

Here is a link explaining the search in general on an Android app:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#PerformingSearch

This link shows how to create and access the virtual table to use for the queries:
http://developer.android.com/training/search/search.html

Also, a full example on this blog:
http://blog.andresteingress.com/2011/09/30/android-quick-tip-using-sqlite-fts-tables/

Basically a virtual table must be created, with for example this query:

```
private static final String FTS_TABLE_CREATE =
                "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE +
                " USING fts3 (" +
                COL_WORD + ", " +
                COL_DEFINITION + ")";
```

Then a cursor can be retrieved using the function `getWordMatches` below:

```
public Cursor getWordMatches(String query, String[] columns) {
    String selection = COL_WORD + " MATCH ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {query+"*"};

    return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);
}

private Cursor query(String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String[] columns) {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    builder.setTables(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);

    Cursor cursor = builder.query(mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
            columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.close();
        return null;
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

All this is coming from the Android documentation, see link above.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to [use an index with a `LIKE` prefix lookup](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#like_opt),

1. the column must have `TEXT` [affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity), i.e., declared as `TEXT` or `VARCHAR` or something like that; and
2. the index must be case insensitive:

   ```
   CREATE INDEX ele_value_idx ON search_eng(r_ele_value COLLATE NOCASE)
   ```

Comment: how to use that created index? or just calling indexed column is enough?

Comment: Indexes are used automatically. Check with [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html).